# How can clear React Material AutoComplete selected label clear if state empty?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have a state :

```
  const [searchEntryNo, setSearchEntryNo] = useState('');
```

Then I have a function to clear state like that.

```
  const handleClear = () => {
    setSearchEntryNo('');
  };
```

***Then There React AutoComplete :***

```
           <Autocomplete
              className={classes.searchBox}
              id="combo-box-demo"
              size="small"
              options={entryList}
              getOptionLabel={(option) => option}
              onChange={(event, newValue) => {
                setSearchEntryNo(newValue);
              }}
              style={{ width: 300 }}
              renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} variant="outlined" 
                      placeholder="Searching" size="small" />}
            />
```

***Note: entryList is the a array state***

***There is a button where handleClear() function fired the button click:***

```
<Button onClick={handleClear}> Clear </Button>
```

***Now I want to clear selected label from AutoComplete Box after handleClear() fired.
How can I solve the issue?***
Please Help me!!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onChange` also passes a second parameter to the change handler: [docs](https://material-ui.com/api/autocomplete/)

```
onChange={(_, value: any, reason: string) => {
 if (value) {
    // seState
 }
if (reason === "clear") {
    // clear State
 }
}}
```